# Integrate SMSA Express with Shopify using SOAP Web Service

Tags: shopify, soapui, webservice-client, shopify-app, integrate

We have a Shopify Store that is almost on its way to complete. Now, we want to integrate shipping service (SMSA Express) with Shopify Store that we needed using a technology "SOAP-based web service". Can anyone please guide me regarding the following questions?

1. Which tool/software should we have to use for web service? Does it work with Visual Studio 2019 or need any other? Recommend language also (PHP, C#).
2. Please guide where the link of Shopify would be given to associate it?
3. Any step by step tutorial available for the Shopify integration via SOAP web service? If any, please provide the link as we are unable to find?

Any other suggestions to make it run successfully would be welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: I feel bad for you! SOAP is one of those technologies put out there by Microsoft way back in the day that never caught on except in a Microsoft world. It is so flakey to work with! It is a hack of XML and HTTP whereas the modern world moved on, and just uses HTTP and now JSON, or GraphQL... Good luck to you!

Comment: yeah, I can understand. It's a drawback using it in this modern era of a large number of advanced technologies but Alas! I have a project's requirements from a client. 
Anyway, thanks for suggesting me up.

Comment: Your request is way too general for anyone to help you, not to mention there is no chance of matching your skills with any tech, since your skills are unknown. Shopify is like any other web platform. Standard stuff. oAuth, HTTP. If you can handle that, and add to it SOAP, that is all you need. So use what works for YOU. Do not worry about Shopify. It just works for almost language except maybe COBOL and FORTRAN, LISP or FORTH. So have at it as you wish.